# deploying angular app in container fails to run ng command

Tags: angular, docker

I'm trying to run my angular app in using google cloud run in a docker container. I've tried some different dockerfile approaches but i haven't managed to get my app running yet.

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This approach seems to build it properly but it can't start the container and after a while it just timesouts. "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found." which seems very odd to me since i do install angular/cli in my container. "

Then i made my own simpler approach:

```
FROM node:12.19.0
WORKDIR /
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install    
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY . .
CMD npm start
```

This fails with the error "ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information."

I'm very new to google cloud run and also to docker container so I guess it could be something very simple and obvious that i've missed here.

Thanks!

EDIT

package.json

```
{
  "name": "LunchTime",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start-proxy": " --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.1.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.6",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^10.1.7",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-masonry": "^10.0.6",
    "node": "^14.14.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.6.1",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.1.6",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^10.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.13",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share your `package.json` please?

Comment: sure @nclskfm! Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: In your initial Dockerfile, it shouldn't be running an `ng` command when the container starts; it will pick up the `CMD` from the `nginx` image you're starting from and launch Nginx with the built application bundled in.  How are you starting the container?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem related to Google Cloud.

You said the image is built, but the runtime error is weird, because from a Nginx point of view, it has no clue the files it's serving are from Angular. So, to begin with, I'd check whether the image is actually created correctly. In other words, since you reach Stage 2, Angular no longer exists.

The second error about the PORT environment variable might be that something else is already listening on such port.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe found your issue in your first `Dockerfile`. You set Workdir to `/app` and afterwards you copy all files (`package.json` and `.`) to `/app`.

`COPY` is relative to `WORKDIR`, so your finaly path would be `/app/app/`. Perhaps you are not aware of this? Because in your `package.json` you did not change the directory to `./app`. Please check this out. :)

**Some other notes for using angular with docker**

- Use `npm ci`  instead `npm install` for automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment. More informations why and how [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci).
- I do not know if you are need `RUN npm install -g @angular/cli` separately. For the Docker start only, you do not need this. Maybe you can try it out and give me some feedback. :)
- If you are need `WORKDIR` you do not need `RUN mkdir -p /app`. Workdir does it automatically.

**So the Dockerfile should something like that:**

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

**EDIT**: Removed `RUN mkdir -p /app`. See notes for the reason.

Comment: Step 4/8 : RUN npm ci
 ---> Running in 68a66917e56d
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.

Comment: I do have a package-lock.json. Do i need to update my node-version?

Comment: i changed to run npm i instead since that worked and then it builds but I end up at the last step with a timeout.  

"Step #2 - "Deploy": Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
Step #2 - "Deploy": gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
TIMEOUT
ERROR: context deadline exceeded"

Comment: hmm I'm not familiar with Google Cloud. Does the `Dockerfile` work locally now?

Comment: The right-hand side of `COPY` obeys the normal Unix path rules: absolute paths like `/app` are absolute paths within the image, and relative paths like `.` are interpreted relative to the current `WORKDIR`.